# Can I print just one column of cards in Trello?

Tags: trello, printing

I want to print just one of many columns in my Trello project. Can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not, you can only print a single board.

A work-around hack:

1. Temporarily re-order your card lists to put the list you want to
   print first on your board.
2. Select print from the board options.
3. In the print preview, only select the first X pages
   that correspond to your first list (you may get the top of your next list on).